# How to compile CoreCLR (compilation problems)?

Tags: .net, linux, coreclr

I have a problem compiling CoreCLR on Linux (Linux Mint 64-bit).
There is one error and two messages (Sorry for the translation from my language):

```
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/artifacts/obj/coreclr/Linux.x64.Checked/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/artifacts/obj/coreclr/Linux.x64.Checked/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  /home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/coreclr
  Executing cmake --build "/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/artifacts/obj/coreclr/Linux.x64.Checked" --target install -- -j 4
  make: *** There are no rules to execute the object 'install'. Stop.
  Failed to build "CoreCLR component".
/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/coreclr/runtime.proj(38,5): error MSB3073: Command „"/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/coreclr/build-runtime.sh" -x64 -checked -os Linux” has been finished with error code 2.

Compilation WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL.

/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/coreclr/runtime.proj(38,5): error MSB3073: Command „"/home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/coreclr/build-runtime.sh" -x64 -checked -os Linux” has been finished with error code 2.
    Warnings: 0
    Errors: 1
```

https://pastebin.com/tZ6rFDqC
This is the output of build.sh from the official .NET Runtime repository
How do I install these packages not found?

Comment: Can you include a *complete* log? The runtime build likes to hid the actual error in the middle of lots of noise.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m2TaKGuk
I only used ./build.sh now. The error was different

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message from your build log:

```
CMake Error at /home/mdev/Desktop/runtime/src/libraries/Native/Unix/System.Net.Security.Native/extra_libs.cmake:18 (message):
Cannot find libgssapi_krb5 and System.Net.Security.Native cannot build
without it.  Try installing libkrb5-dev (or the appropriate package for
your platform)
```

Can you install the kerberos development headers? The exact command will depend on your distro. For example, it's `dnf install krb5-devel` on Fedora.

Comment: Error still occurs. There is apparently a CMAKE error:
CMake error log:
https://pastebin.com/r4VYupTD (NEW LINK)

Comment: It's normal to have a cmake error log. It contains a record of all cmake tests that dont work. And it's normal to have cmake tests that fail, because that's cmake's job: check which features are not available. The cmake log still shows the original error, though, so you haven't installed the right packages, I think: `fatal error: 'gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h' file not found`

Comment: What isn't working? Can you provide more information about what you have done and what you haven't?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I installed krb5. The error is still there. I noticed that more files are missing but it looks like they are only for windows. 
Log from build: https://pastebin.com/VER8VRpp
Log from CMake output: https://pastebin.com/cWvtQmqd
Log from Cmake errors: https://pastebin.com/xyumBZne

Comment: The new error is `Cannot find libssl`. The error message also says: `try installing libssl-dev`. You should do that.

Comment: Haha, it's very simple problem. Thank you. I built runtime but can you help me with .net sdk building? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264982/how-to-build-net-sdk-from-source